# In my Django app following error occoured

Tags: django-forms

Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices. error occurred in django. how to solve this?

My Model is look likew

```
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    menu = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Chapter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Content(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Form is look like

```
from django import forms
from .models import Course, Category, Chapter, Content


class AddContent(forms.ModelForm):
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all(), empty_label='Select category', required=False)
    course = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Course.objects.none(), empty_label="Select Course", required=False)
    chapter = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Chapter.objects.none(), empty_label="Select Chapter")

    class Meta:
        model = Content
        fields = ('category', 'course', 'chapter', 'title', 'slug', 'body')
```

View is look like

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django_dump_die.middleware import dd
from .models import Category, Course, Chapter, Content
from .forms import CourseForm, AddContent
from django.urls import reverse_lazy


class ContentListView(ListView):
    model = Content
    template_name = 'backend/content/content_list.html'


class ContentDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Content
    template_name = 'backend/content/content_detail.html'


class ContentCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Content
    form_class = AddContent
    template_name = 'backend/content/content_new.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('content_list')


class ContentUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Content
    template_name = 'backend/content/content_edit.html'
    fields = ['chapter', 'title', 'slug', 'body']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('content_list')


class ContentDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Content
    template_name = 'backend/content/content_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('content_list')


def get_course(request):
    category_id = request.GET.get('category_id')
    courses = Course.objects.filter(category_id=category_id).values('id', 'title')
    return JsonResponse(list(courses), safe=False)


def get_chapter(request):
    course_id = request.GET.get('course_id')
    chapters = Chapter.objects.filter(course_id=course_id).values('id', 'name')
    return JsonResponse(list(chapters), safe=False)


def form_view(request):
    form = CourseForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

Template is look like

```
{% extends '_base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Add New</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        {#$('#id_chapter').prop('disabled', true);#}
        {#$('#id_course').prop('disabled', true);#}
        $('#id_category').change(function () {
            let category_id = $(this).val();
            $('#id_course').prop('disabled', false);
            if (category_id) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/get_courses/',
                    data: {
                        'category_id': category_id
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                            $('#id_course').append($('<option></option>').attr('value', value.id).text(value.title));
                        });
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $('#id_course').empty();
            }
        });

        $('#id_course').change(function () {
            let course_id = $(this).val();
            $('#id_chapter').prop('disabled', false);
            console.log(course_id);
            if (course_id) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/get_chapters/',
                    data: {
                        'course_id': course_id
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                            $('#id_chapter').append($('<option></option>').attr('value', value.id).text(value.name));
                        });
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $('#id_chapter').empty();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
{% endblock content %}
```

Screen shot of error is look like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reVmW.png)

I will try to save the content but show validation error